# How to use skpsmtpmessage?

Tags: iphone, email, ipad, skpsmtpmessage

Im trying implement an email functionality in my app without presenting a modal view. Many people have suggested using skpsmtpmessage library. Iv downloaded this library and started a new project with it just to test it, but im not having any idea on how to start out with it. What do i need to do to test this library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://mhmethun.wordpress.com/iphone/send-email-with-attaching-file-using-smtp-server/

follow above link ....i have followed above one and got result